# Angular mat components height alignment

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I adjust the height, so that the height of the `.container` and `mat-button` is determined by the height of the mat-form-fields?

I've commented out the container in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-material-starter-xgxqha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) example, because it destroys the alignment of the items within.

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <div class="container">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Category">
                <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Search" />
            <button mat-button matSuffix>
                <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```